# Creating SQL Server tables with formula

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-express

I want to create a database `MyDatabase` programmatically.

I want to create a table `Table1` in that database, with some columns `Columns1, Columns2, Columns3...`.

But some of my columns are having formula in it. And of course, my formula is based on other columns.

So suppose `Column1` is having formula based on values of `column2` and `column3`. And therefore not having any datatype defined.

So how to create tables with formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about [**computed columns**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) in SQL Server, then you just create them like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderLine
(OrderLineID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 ProductID INT NOT NULL,   -- FK to Products table
 ItemPrice DECIMAL(16, 4),
 Quantity DECIMAL(10, 2),
 TotalPrice AS ItemPrice * Quantity   -- this is a computed column right here
)
```